# Gradient of a real-valued function on SO(3)

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

I have struggling with a problem of evaluating **the gradient** of a cost function on the Lie group of rotations: SO(3). The cost is the following:

\begin{equation} V_M(R)=\frac{1}{2}⟨\log(R),M\log(R)⟩,\;\;\;R\in\mathrm{SO(3)}\end{equation}
for some matrix $M=M^{\mathsf T}>0$.

The inner product is given by $⟨A,B⟩:=\operatorname{tr}(A^{\mathsf T} B)$. The logarithm function on SO(3) is defined to be:
\begin{equation}
\log(R)=\frac{\theta}{2\sin(\theta)}(R-R^{\mathsf T})\in\mathfrak{so}(3)
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ represents the angle of rotation ($R:=\exp(\theta[u]_\times)=I+\sin(\theta)[u]_\times+(1-\cos(\theta))[u]_\times^2$  )

I have tried to use the fact that for some $X\in T_R\mathrm{SO(3)}$, we have
\begin{equation}
dV[X]=⟨\nabla V,X⟩
\end{equation}
but I was not able even to determine the directional derivative $dV[X]$...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The logarithm on SO(3) is a multi-valued function. We see, given formula for it experiences a singularity at *θ* = π.

Comment: It is a multivalued function only on the domain of all rotations of angle $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the gradient of $V_M(R)$ in the case where $M=I_3$. In this case, the gradient of $V_M(R)$ is simply given by:
$$
\nabla V(R)=\log(R)
$$ 
You can have a look a the following paper for a proof: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896315004723

It is still an open problem for a general positive definite matrix $M$.